# Eigenvectors of $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking at a $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For the eigenvalues I have

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{a+d}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{(a+d)^{2}}{4}-ad+b^{2}}$$

Now, I'm trying to find an eigenvector $(u_{1}, u_{2})^{T}$ corresponding to $\lambda_{1}$.

To do so, I start with

$$(a-\lambda)u_{1}+bu_{2} = 0$$

which comes from the formulation of the eigenproblem. I know that in order to solve this I have to choose $u_{1}$ or $u_{2}$ arbitrarily and substitute in $\lambda_{1}$. Doing so yields:

$$u_{1} = - \frac{bu_{2}}{a-\lambda_{1}}$$. Choosing $u_{2} = 1$, I get $(-b, a-\lambda_{1})^{T}$. Comparing this with the output from wolfram alpha, it seems my coordinates are reversed. This is the output I'm referring to: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors%20%7B%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%2C%20%7Bc%2C%20d%7D%7D&lk=2

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I looks you got it correct... **if** $\;b\neq 0\;$ . Read below.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

$$p_A(t)=\det (tI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}t-a&-b\\-b&t-d\end{vmatrix}=t^2-(a+d)t+ad-b^2$$

The quadratic's discriminant is

$$\Delta=(a+d)^2-4(ad-b^2)=(a-d)^2+4b^2\ge 0\stackrel{\text{the root(s)}}\implies\;\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{(a+d)\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2}$$

Forming the homogeneous system to find eigenvectors:

$$(\lambda_1-a)x-by=0\implies \begin{cases}y=\frac{\lambda_1-a}bx\;,\;\;b\neq 0\implies\binom b{\lambda_1-a}\;\text{is an eigenvector}\\{}\\x=0\;,\;\;y\in\Bbb F,\;\;b=0\,,\,\,\lambda_1\neq a\implies\binom01\;\text{is an eigenvector}\\{}\\x,y\in\Bbb F\;,\;\;b=\lambda_1-a=0\implies\binom10\,,\,\,\binom01\;\;\text{are eigenvectors}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I should have added that I'm assuming $b \neq 0$. However, I still don't understand why WolframAlpha has essentially the reciprocals of the components I have. To achieve this I would have to set $u_{1} = 1$. WolframAlpha seems to have $u_{2} = 1$ instead.

Comment: @user2249626 In the link to WA you put, the matrix has $\;c\;$ insteado of $\;b\;$ , as shown in your question above...

Comment: Oh sorry about that. It still appears that my numerator and denominator are reversed and that the only way to get them correct is to set $u_{1} = 1$ instead of $u_{2} = 1$ as shown by WolframAlpha (see: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7Ba%2C+b%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+d%7D%7D)

Comment: @user2249626 Perhaps so...but who cares?! First, WA is wrong not that few times, and second: take your eigenvector and *prove* it **actually** is an eigenvector. Got it? Who cares what WA says! Didn't get it? There's a mistake somewhere and we must check.